# Expectation of a continuous random variable on a discrete random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

A dice is thrown. If the result is $Y$ , then we let $X$ be uniform between $0$ and $Y$ . Find $E(X)$.

I know how to find the expectation of a continuous and a discrete RV, but how do I combine them? I am guessing that the formula is something like $\frac{1}{6}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{6}i/2$, but I'm not sure about this.

Comment: Your guess is correct, and your formula is an application of the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ is drawn from one of six different distributions uniformly at random:

- with probability $\frac16$, $U(0,1)$ is chosen
- with probability $\frac16$, $U(0,2)$ is chosen, etc.

The expected values of these sub-distributions are $\frac12$, 1, $\frac32$, 2, $\frac52$ and 3 respectively. Since expectation is linear, we can merely take the average of these expected values to obtain the expectation of $X$:
$$E[X]=\frac{\frac12+1+\frac32+2+\frac52+3}6=\frac74$$
which in fact matches what you expected $E[X]$ to be.

Answer (score 1):

$$\mathsf E X|Y=\frac y 2$$
$$\mathsf E (X)=\mathsf E(\mathsf E X|Y)=\mathsf E(\frac y 2)=\frac{1}{6}(\frac 1 2+\frac 2 2+\frac 3 2+\frac 4 2+\frac 5 2+\frac 6 2)=\frac {21} {12}$$

Comment: So my guess was correct?

Comment: Yes. It is iterated expectation.